# How to add custom reactjs components (belle) to my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I want to add custom react components ([belle](http://nikgraf.github.io/belle/#/)) to my rails app.
I'm using react-rails 1.0.0 for my view layer which i write it with coffeescript.

First of all i am new to Reactjs and my steps thanks to this site [Bring CommonJS to your asset pipeline](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/04/bring-commonjs-to-your-asset-pipeline/) moves to [browserify-rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails)
I installed browserify as is on the github page and arkency blog.
Then i run `npm install --save belle` in the console, i added to my application.js :

```
var belle = require('belle');
TextInput = belle.TextInput;
```

At the end i added to my main component simple component from Belle

`'<TextInput defaultValue={Update here and see how the input grows} />'`

Below my sites.js.coffee file:

```
@Sites = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    sites: @props.data
  getDefaultState: ->
    sites: []
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: 'sites_wrapper'
      '<TextInput defaultValue={Update here and see how the input grows} />'
      for site in @state.sites       
        React.DOM.div
          className: 'col-md-4 text-center'
          React.createElement Site, key: site.id, site: site, articles: site.articles
```

The result is that, now i have blank, white page.
This way - add custom component to my rails app, is good?
or is any better way to do this? If for the first question, answer is 'yes', what i make wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm can't help you with the Rails part, but I noticed in front of `TextInput` a var declaration is missing. This was a mistake in the getting started part of the Belle readme.

Correct version:

`var TextInput = belle.TextInput;`